# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Due to one of the DE's not including a subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

```
SELECT
ob.SubscriberKey,
ob.EmailAddress,
ob.fname, 
ob.Country,
ob.Language, 
ob.fin_no,
dw.username,
dw.password,
fp.FirstOrderDate

 

FROM FP_Onboarding_Root AS ob
LEFT JOIN Active_FP_JP AS fp ON fp.SID = ob.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN ent.DISTWELCOME_JP AS dw ON dw.EmailAddress = ob.EmailAddress

 

WHERE (fp.FirstOrderDate is null OR fp.FirstOrderDate = '')
AND ob.EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
```

This works fine in query studio and pull all the relevant data, but as soon as I put it in an automation I get the error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key.

I am only using the SubscriberKey as primary key in the DE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query Error Violation of PRIMARY KEY](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317288/sql-query-error-violation-of-primary-key)

Comment: also, it works fine in the Query Studio only because of the fact that Query Studio creates temporary Data Extension without specific structure and primary keys, thus you can have there all possible values, including duplicated ones.

Comment: ** so I figured this out, ent.DISTWELCOME_JP did not have a subscriberkey and was being sourced by email, I had the Automation set to Update!!!!!

If I set the Automation DE to override  the the automation runs fine and the DE is populated.